# How Can I Execute a DataSeries Fill While Referencing a ListBox Choice?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a user-friendly worksheet in which the user can identify if they want their data series to grow using growth type "xlLinear" or "xlGrowth".

I have created a ListBox in which the choices are "Linear" or "Growth". From there, I would like the data series to fill based on the fill type in that ListBox. As of now, I am getting a "DataSeries Method of Range Class Failed" error, which I have attributed to the "Type" parameter in the data series code.

I'm fairly new to vba, though I have tried pulling the content of the ListBox cell using .Value, .Text, and just the range itself. I do not believe the ListBox is the issue, as the same problem occurs when removing the ListBox and simply typing "Linear" or "Growth".

Below, "RevStream1GrowthType" refers to the ListBox cell. The first portion of the code presents no issues - only the second part.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Inputs")

Range(.Range("RevStream1Ter").Offset(0, 3 + HistoricNumber + AnalystNumber), .Range("RevStream1GrowthValue")).Name = "Test1"

.Range("Test1").DataSeries Rowcol:=xlRows, Type:="xl" & .Range("RevStream1GrowthType"), Date:=xlDay, Trend:=True

End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xlLinear` (actually, `xlDataSeriesLinear`) and `xlGrowth` are members of Excel `XlDataSeriesType` enumeration, and you can refer to them either through the enumeration name followed by a dot and then the wanted member (e.g.: `XlDataSeriesType.xlGrowth`) or directly by their value (e.g.: `-4132` for xlDataSeriesLinear). No way you can use a string (be it a constant or a variable) to *call* the wanted enumeration: `"xlLinear"` or `"xlGrowth"` wouldn't work.

so you must use some function that, fed with your listbox as its input, returns the proper `XlDataSeriesType` enumeration value.

like, for instance:

```
.Range("Test1").DataSeries Rowcol:=xlRows, Type:=IIf(.Range("RevStream1GrowthType").Value = "Linear", xlLinear, xlGrowth), Date:=xlDay, Trend:=True
```